# jQuery append several similar items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid of items (several rows with a fixed max number of product cards in each row) which i want to re-arrange depending on screen resolution (1 card in xs, 2 in sm, 3 in lg+).
I have this code:

```
var recommendedProductCards = $('#upsell .product-col');

function renderRecommendedProductsCarousel(recommendedProductCardsPerRow) {
    if (recommendedProductCards.length) {

        var currentProductRowsNumber = $('#products-grid .row').length;

        recommendedProductCards.each(function (index, productCard) {

            if (index % recommendedProductCardsPerRow == 0) {
                $('#products-grid').append('<div class="item row products-row"></div>');
            }

            $('#products-grid .item').last().append(productCard);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < currentProductRowsNumber; i++) {
            $('#products-grid .item').first().remove();
        }
    }
}
```

However, for example when moving items from 3 per row to 2 per row, every 2nd appended item is not displayed and is not appearing in the DOM inside the `$('#products-grid .item').last()` row on the same level with the first item.

The CSS path to the product card is `#upsell #products-grid .item .product-col`.

Comment: try `$('#products-grid > .item').last().append(productCard);` the selector could be the problem...

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you!